# views information in exposed form hook

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I am trying to compare views in exposed form but so far there is no way I am getting views information in exposed form. Is there any way to do so? I need to compare view id for theme suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view and display of an exposed form are stored in `$form_state`.

```
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $view = $form_state->get('view');
  $display = $form_state->get('display');
}
```

Comment: Thank you mradcliffe. Where can I find the documentation of such functions.

Comment: I like going to api.drupal.org and looking up class names and such.